# How to get cookies value in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I get the value of a cookie.

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'Cookie=HELLO');
});
```

For example, I've been making cookies as I can to get its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be get by `req.cookies`.

```
res.cookie('user', '...'); # set cookie['user'] as '...'
req.cookies['user'] // get cookie['user']
req.headers.cookie // get cookie string like //user=...;session=...
```

For example,

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('user', '...'); 
  console.log("req.cookies['user'] => ", req.cookies['user'])
  console.log("req.headers.cookie => ", req.headers.cookie)
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

The console are shown as below:

[image]